# Syncfusion DataForm Validation with MVVM RelayCommand Button

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui, syncfusion

I have a Syncfusion sfDataForm binding to my Order object. I want to do some specific validation on the fields before the save to the database can be initiated (specifically Date fields, I need one of the dates to be greater than or equal to the current date). The Button for the save is wired to the RelayCommand using the MVVM community toolkit. Any help is appreciated.

Xaml

```xml
<dataForm:SfDataForm
    x:Name="dataForm"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.Column="1"
    DataObject="{Binding Order}"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    LayoutType="TextInputLayout">
    <dataForm:SfDataForm.Behaviors>
        <local:DataFormBehavior />
    </dataForm:SfDataForm.Behaviors>
</dataForm:SfDataForm>

<Button
    Grid.Row="2"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"
    HeightRequest="50"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    Style="{StaticResource PrimaryAction}"
    Text="Cancel"
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    WidthRequest="200" />
```

CodeBehind

```
public partial class NewOrderPage : ContentPage
{
    public NewOrderPage(NewOrderViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel;

        this.dataForm.GenerateDataFormItem += OnGenerateDataFormItem;
    }


    private void OnGenerateDataFormItem(object? sender, GenerateDataFormItemEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> hiddenFormItems = new List<string>() { "Id", "StoreId", "ScheduleDate", "OrderPlacementDate", "ShippedDate", "InstallationDate", "InvoiceDate" };

        if (e.DataFormItem != null)
        {
            if (hiddenFormItems.Contains(e.DataFormItem.FieldName))
            {
                e.DataFormItem.IsVisible = false;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

ViewModel

```
   public Order Order { get; set; }
    private IDataAccess<Order> dataAccess;

    public NewOrderViewModel()
        : this(MauiProgram.GetService<IDialogService>(), MauiProgram.GetService<INavigationService>(), MauiProgram.GetService<IDataAccess<Order>>())
    {
    }

    public NewOrderViewModel(IDialogService dialogService, INavigationService navigationService, IDataAccess<Order> dataAccess)
        : base(dialogService, navigationService)
    {
        Title = "New Order";
        this.Order = new Order();
        this.dataAccess = dataAccess;
    }


    [RelayCommand]
    private async Task SaveAsync()
    {
        if(this.Order != null)
        {
            dataAccess.Insert(this.Order);
        }
        await DialogService.DisplayAlertAsync("Add Event", "Would you like to add this order?", "OK");
        await NavigationService.PopModalAsync();
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    private Task CancelAsync() => NavigationService.PopModalAsync();
}
```

I have tried some validation with attributes on the Order model. I quickly realized since Min and Max dates for the DataFormDateRange attribute must be const strings, I cannot use DateTime Now to validate there. I tried using sys assembly in my xaml to validate with the current date time but seemed to crash the application on validation.

Comment: Please do NOT post code or errors as images

Comment: https://support.syncfusion.com/kb/article/12376/how-to-set-the-minimum-and-maximum-date-for-the-date-editor-in-net-maui-dataform-sfdataform

Comment: Thank you for the insight, that article was helpful. I was unaware posting images of code was frowned upon I will remove them. Thank you! @Jason

Comment: It is always good practice to supply text instead of images since it can be copied (e.g. if you want people to try your code you got to give people a chance to run your code, and likewise, you got to give people the ability to do searches with your error strings).